# Travel Itinerary Change: Should I notify the consulate?

Tags: visas, customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, schengen-visas

I have received a multiple-entry Schengen visa from the Spanish consulate in Mumbai for a meeting that was originally scheduled for the 9th of January, but now has been moved to the 23rd of January. The visa has a validity of 45 days, so it will be valid for my entire stay.

Since I've had to both re-book my flight tickets and change my hotel (due to availability issues), should I notify the consulate about these changes? I've heard of people getting their visas annulled or revoked due to similar things, hence my apprehension. Is there any chances that sending the consulate the new itinerary might lead to any issues with future applications or at passport control?

Comment: Update: I've sent the visa section an email. I'll add another update here if and when I receive it, but answers are still welcome.

Comment: If you’re still following the overall itinerary I don’t think they’ll care at all about the date change. Travel plans change all the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the new travel dates fit into your **duration** and **validity period**, there is no need to inform the consulate -- business meetings get rescheduled all the time, and that's why most applicants get a few extra days on their visa.

The immigration officers might ask on arrival, simply show them your new travel plans and tickets.

If the new dates exceed either the duration or the validity period, of course you will need a new visa.

Answer (score 1):

I received the following response from the visa section of the Spanish consulate in Mumbai.

> Good morning,
>
> Kindly note as you have been granted a multiple entry visa valid until
>   XX-XX-2020, you may travel as many times on any given days during the
>   validity of the visa. You need not send any notification to the
>   Consulate. However, kindly note permission to enter or denying entry
>   into the territory is the decision of the immigration authorities.
>
> Regards, Jefe de Visado / Visa Officer
>   Sección de Visados/Visa Section

Since this matches the information in @o.m.'s answer, I am accepting it.